# ASP DevExpress libraries undefined after server migration

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, migration, devexpress, undefined-reference

I'm having trouble migrating the DevExpress elements of an ASP web application from one server to another.  I basically copied the files and database over into a new server location and made some adjustments to the web.config file to get it connected to the new database.  That got most of the site working and pulling data correctly, but the DevExpress pieces are coming up as undefined.

As far as I can tell, the references in the web.config file and on the respective pages is correct and the dll files themselves are listed in the bin directory so I'm rather stumped as to why they aren't working.

**Web.config sample**

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
   <assemblies>
    ...
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v10.1, Version=10.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.1, Version=10.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
    ... and so on
```

**Dashboard.aspx sample**

```
...at top of page...
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v10.1, Version=10.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" tagprefix="dx" %>
```

This was an inherited project, so I haven't tried rebuilding the application in case my machine imports my settings into the project (example: it was made in VS 2008, and I'm running VS Community 2015).

Are there any quirks to making a transfer like this that I just don't know about or has anyone else experienced this issue?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is that version 10.1 of DevExpress is a very old version, released in Aug '10. It does not support .Net 4, so you'll need to make sure the application pool for IIS running this web app is .NET CLR Version 2.0.

Note that if you are running in Windows Server 2012, it's actually tricky to install .Net 3.5. Google how to do it if you need to.

The next to check of course if all of the dll's referenced are in the Bin folder.

Could you write the error message you are getting? If it does not have any extra information, perhaps the event viewer of the server (under windows logs/applications) has a more detailed description.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Harry.  
Our server has .Net 4 and .Net 3.5 installed.  I've double checked the dlls are all in the Bin folder.

Here's one of the error messages that comes up:
`var dxo = new ASPxClientWebChartControl('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebChartControl1');
'ASPxClientWebChartControl' is undefined `

Comment: Thanks again Harry, I found there was an import line in the web.config file that was commented out.  Specifically in the <modules> tag.  We can consider this resolved.